# Как сделать так, чтобы setInterval работал корректно на мобильных устройствах

Tags: javascript, таймер

Во время тестирования своего сайта на телефоне, я увидел, что таймер замедляется примерно в 2 раза. На сайте есть раздел с CPS тестом (click per second), время обновления таймера, а соответственно и поля с показателем CPS - 10 миллисекунд. На ПК все работает как надо. На сколько я понял проблема состоит в том, что действия которые должны выполняться раз в 10 миллисекунд на более слабых устройствах выполняются дольше => таймер замедляется.

Какие действия мне стоит предпринять и в чем я ошибся?

P.S. На JSе пишу первый раз, так то не бейте. Весь проект есть на GitHub'e: https://github.com/S1riyS/CLICKSPEED

```
import { parseURLParams } from './modules/url_parser.js';

let isTestStarted = false,
    clicks = 0, // clicks
    cps = 0, // clicks per second
    countdownValue = parseURLParams(window.location.href)['test_time'][0], // seconds
    time = 0, // current time in timer
    timer;

const counter = document.getElementById('counter'),
    timerElement = document.getElementById('timer'),
    cpsCounter = document.getElementById('cps'),
    clickButton = document.getElementById('start-btn'),
    clickArea = document.getElementById('click-area');


// Функция, которая отрабатывает при нажатии на "кнопку"
function startGame() {
    clicks++;
    counter.innerHTML = clicks;

    if (isTestStarted == false) {
        time = 0;
        isTestStarted = true;
        startTestLoop();
        clickButton.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

// Привязка функции к кнопке начала и игровому полю
clickButton.onclick = startGame;
clickArea.onclick = startGame;

// Обновления содержимого HTML элементов
function updateHTML(time) {
    let dateTimer = new Date(time);
    let currentTime =
        dateTimer.getUTCSeconds() + '.' +
        ('0' + dateTimer.getUTCMilliseconds()).slice(-3, -1);

    timerElement.innerHTML = currentTime
    cpsCounter.innerHTML = (clicks / (time / 1000)).toFixed(2);
}
// Главная функция
function startTestLoop() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        time += 10;
        updateHTML(time);
        
        if (time >= countdownValue * 1000) {
            timerElement.innerHTML = countdownValue + ".00"
            clicks = 0;
            cps = 0;
            clickButton.innerHTML = 'Click here to start playing';
            clearInterval(timer);
            isTestStarted = false;
        }
    }, 10)
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame

Comment: В том что асинхронная очередь `setInterval` и `setTimeout` ждет возможности выполнять итерации вместо их пропуска, и заключается корректное поведение. То есть, оно не сломано, так и должно быть. Вот очередь rAF (по ссылке в предыдущем комменте) - работает иначе, там итерации по необходимости пропускаются, вместо ожидания возможности их выполнения. Но интервал можно реализовать только проверкой времени в условии выхода из функции, и он тоже будет не идеально точен (если верно помню, точность "плавает" в пределах размера "кванта" интервала таймера, который составляет около 17мс, 1/60 секунды).